# Deploy Windows IOT Core app remotely

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, ota, windowsiot

I have multiple devices running Windows IOT Core in different locations. Is there a way to remotely update and deploy the foreground app of selected devices with an app package over the internet somehow?
I can not use port forewarding in every router. Something like teamviewer for the device portal would be ideal.

Comment: Have you checked [device portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal).

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Update apps on your Windows 10 IoT Core devices](http:///https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps) (12/07/2017)

OEMs and enterprise customers can deliver app updates to Windows 10 IoT Core devices in the following ways:

- Using Microsoft Store: The app is published and updated from the Microsoft Store
- Using Device Update Center: The app is published to Windows Update and updated like any other OEM package (driver package) Coming soon
- Using Azure IoT Device Management: The app is published to Azure Storage and updated through the Azure DM channel New for Windows 10, version 1709
- Using OMA-DM: The app is updated using an OMA-DM compliant device management channel such as Intune or System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM)